# How many comparisons are needed in worst case if we have to sort 7 numbers each of 4 digit?

Tags: radix-sort, bucket-sort

How many  comparisons are needed in worst case if we have to sort 7 numbers each of 4 digit ?(Radix sort)
Options are- 40,38,47,280 .

My solution-I have taken 10 buckets( 0 to 9)(linked list) . Then for every number for ith digit I have put it into Bucket corresponding to its digit's value. Then I collected those numbers into array back. This process is repeated for all the digits and thus my original array got sorted. Total number of comparisons= 10*4=40 (10 because I iterated through all buckets to look for corresponding bucket).

Now the problem is in the book by Timothy J Williams its given no of comparisons= no of digits* no of numbers * no of buckets= 4*7*10=280. I am not able to comprehend up. Can someone please explain how this came.

Comment: What counts as a comparison? From a theoretical perspective, radix sort isn't even considered a comparison sort, so the answer would be 0...

Answer (score 2):

It is true that radix sort is not a comparison based algorithm. Here comparisons account to the comparisons involved in iterations. First, we need to traverse the array of 7 elements and keep the digit of each number in the appropriate bucket. Here in order to traverse the array we need 7 comparisons. After placing all the elements in the buckets from 0-9 we need to traverse all the buckets from 0-9 and arrange the elements in order according to their bucket number, this takes 10 comparisons to traverse the bucket from 0-9. Now we have to repeat this process for all the 4 digits of 7 elements. So, the total number of comparisons would be 7*10*4 = 280